# code executes without error but unable to update Access data using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have the following code which executes successfully but does not update data in database. Please consider the part where mode="edit" is true because INSERT works fine.

I have different modes to indicate whether to update or insert. Insert works fine with all database fields but update does not work: it does not give any errors (execute is successful) but database is not updated.

```
double id; // please consider only edit part
if (mode != "edit")
    id = id_increment();
else
    id = Convert.ToInt64(view_gv.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value.ToString()); //find currrent row successfully
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
con.ConnectionString = con_string;
con.Open();
com.Connection = con;
if (mode != "edit")
{
    com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TBLPERSONMST] ([ID],[name],[address],[city],[o_phone],[r_phone],[mo_number],[email],[dob],[ann_date],[bg],[sex],[group]) VALUES (@id,@name,@add,@city,@ophone,@rphone,@mophone,@email,@dob,@ann_date,@bg,@sex,@group)";

}
else
{
    com.CommandText = "UPDATE [TBLPERSONMST] SET [name]=@name,[address]=@add,[city]=@city,[o_phone]=@ophone,[r_phone]=@rphone,[mo_number]=@mophone,[email]=@email,[dob]=@dob,[ann_date]=@ann_date,[bg]=@bg,[sex]=@sex,[group]=@group WHERE [ID]=@id";

}

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", id));

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@name", name_txt.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@add", add_txt.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@city", city_txt.Text));
if (ophone_txt.Text != "")
    com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ophone", Convert.ToDouble(ophone_txt.Text)));
else
    com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ophone", "0"));
if (rphone_txt.Text != "")
    com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@rphone", Convert.ToDouble(rphone_txt.Text)));
else
    com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@rphone", "0"));
if (mo_txt.Text != "")
    com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@mophone", Convert.ToDouble(mo_txt.Text)));
else
    com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@mophone", "0"));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@email", email_txt.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@dob", dob_date.Value.ToShortDateString()));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ann_date", anni_date.Value.ToShortDateString()));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@bg", bg_cmbox.SelectedItem));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@sex", gen_cmbox.SelectedItem));

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@group", grp_cmbox.SelectedItem));

int j=com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "edit" problem stems from the fact that parameterized queries in ACE/Jet OLEDB **ignore** parameter names and therefore the parameters must be added to the `OleDbCommand` object in the ***exact*** order that they appear in the `CommandText`. Your INSERT and UPDATE commands use the parameters in a different order, so you must process the `com.Parameters.Add` statements in a different order depending on whether you are doing an INSERT or an UPDATE ("edit").

Comment: Thanks sir. i got solution after post question. you are right OELDB ignore parameter name it take parameter in ORDER only..