# cannot insert data into access using c#

Tags: c#

I tried many times but the data cannot be inserted but no errors

please help

```
public static void SaveCorresDetails(string cN, string cId, string pId, string rI)
     {
         OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
         string myQuery = "INSERT INTO RAHANICorrespondent(DateIssue, Action, Recipient, Remarks) VALUES ( '" + cN + "' , '" + cId + "',  '" + pId + "','" + rI + "')";
         OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

         try
         {
             myConnection.Open();
             myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
         }
         finally
         {
             myConnection.Close();
         }

     }
```

and this will be the class file
to add data

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string n = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
        string c = TextBox2.Text.Trim();

        string p = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
        string r = TextBox4.Text.Trim();


        // save the data into the database
        Data.SaveCorresDetails(n, c, p, r);
        Label6.Text = "Package amount of " + n + " was saved";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: What does ExecuteNonQuery return?

Comment: execute non query is used to Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: Or -1 so what is returned? Also is this a console app?

Comment: it returns the value that inserted  and this is web application

Comment: possible duplicate of [code executes without error but unable to update Access data using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130445/code-executes-without-error-but-unable-to-update-access-data-using-c-sharp)

Comment: no... thatis using parameter,

Comment: You won't be able to see anything in the console if it isn't a console app (to my knowledge). What happens when you place a breakpoint on the line where your Console.Writeline is?

Answer (score 0):

Try using db parameters instead.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("");
string query = "INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) Values(@a, @b @c)";
OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("a", "Hi man");
param.DbType = ...
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And then check if your getting errors and log them see if this might help.